# How do I declare a variable for a hard coded database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, if-statement

I have some hard coded database values in my SQL and I need to convert to variables , I have declared them in places but I need Production2 to be changed to @Source_Database_Name variable below but I dont know how to place it in with the Information Schema just after it without getting a syntax error

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT *  FROM Production2.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```

Comment: Is this just Transact-SQL stored in a .sql file? Because `sqlcmd` and `sqlcmd mode` in SSMS allow you to use variables. Otherwise it's dynamic SQL/synonyms/linked servers for you. If these are stored procedures and deployed to different environments you can also use something like SQL Server Data Tools to manage them. SQL Server Data Tools has variables you can use in your T-SQL.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the only way you can do this is dynamic sql generation (unfortunately). And there's actually quite a few reasons (from database engine's perspective) for not allowing a user to parametrise queries in a way you want. The one that sits on top of my head is that it will make impossible to validate syntax of your query (no way to know that you're referring to what actually exists).

In case you're talking about "being able to execute the same set of SQL against different database(s)" and you're actually executing this sql from code (.NET / anything), you can achieve the same result by specifying target database in connection string (i.e. by changing the level where you set database -- not in the [sql] script, but rather at some external point).